# How do I plot all rows per column?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2

I am very new to R and I am currently playing around with it, I've run into an issue with plotting the following dataframe that I imported from a CSV.

```
                      studentname dateofbirth GSF3A3U FJÖ1UF05AU EÐLI2GR05BT FOR3D3U FOR3L3DU FOR4A3U ROB2B3U STÆR3FV05ET USA1012 WIN3B3DU userid
1                  Ada Gauidóttir   13.8.1997     8.3        8.0         4.0     6.8      8.5     8.1     4.0         5.9     9.0      9.4      1
2             Gjaflaug Amildóttir   14.6.1998     6.0        6.6         6.2     8.9      4.7     9.4     8.5         8.1     4.3      5.3      2
3              Unndís Jónasdóttir   2.11.1998     8.7        7.8         6.9    10.0      7.0    10.0     9.3         5.4     7.2      5.8      3
4              Sigjón Elfráðurson  14.10.1996     9.3        8.9         6.2     8.1      9.7     5.5     6.8         9.0     6.9      4.2      4
5           Þórbjörg Rökkvidóttir  12.10.2000     4.9        6.9         5.2     6.9      5.3     5.5     5.6         4.8     8.9      9.2      5
6                 Richard Hlérson    3.2.2000     9.4        7.7         8.4     6.1      6.4     9.6     4.9         7.2     9.3      7.0      6
7               Tala Arnalddóttir   18.8.1997     7.9        7.1         6.9     6.0      9.3     5.4     8.1         6.8     5.8      6.7      7
8           Petrína Estefandóttir   24.9.1994     9.6        4.9         5.0     8.4      7.9     8.7     5.5        10.0     4.0      9.5      8
9          Tanja Finnlaugurdóttir   11.7.1993     6.7        6.5         6.9     8.3      6.3     9.6     9.1         4.2     9.6      4.7      9
10                Elly Amosdóttir    6.7.2001     4.8        7.0         4.3     9.5      7.1     4.2     6.6         5.3     9.0      4.4     10
```

I am trying to plot this data so that the course names are on the X-axis and the rows for each course(the grades) are displayed on the Y-axis.

If I use the code below:

```
students[,3:12, drop=FALSE]
```

This result below is exactly what I'm looking for, but how do I scatterplot this?

```
    GSF3A3U FJÖ1UF05AU EÐLI2GR05BT FOR3D3U FOR3L3DU FOR4A3U ROB2B3U STÆR3FV05ET USA1012 WIN3B3DU
1       8.3        8.0         4.0     6.8      8.5     8.1     4.0         5.9     9.0      9.4
2       6.0        6.6         6.2     8.9      4.7     9.4     8.5         8.1     4.3      5.3
3       8.7        7.8         6.9    10.0      7.0    10.0     9.3         5.4     7.2      5.8
4       9.3        8.9         6.2     8.1      9.7     5.5     6.8         9.0     6.9      4.2
5       4.9        6.9         5.2     6.9      5.3     5.5     5.6         4.8     8.9      9.2
6       9.4        7.7         8.4     6.1      6.4     9.6     4.9         7.2     9.3      7.0
7       7.9        7.1         6.9     6.0      9.3     5.4     8.1         6.8     5.8      6.7
8       9.6        4.9         5.0     8.4      7.9     8.7     5.5        10.0     4.0      9.5
9       6.7        6.5         6.9     8.3      6.3     9.6     9.1         4.2     9.6      4.7
10      4.8        7.0         4.3     9.5      7.1     4.2     6.6         5.3     9.0      4.4
```

Comment: Reshape to long form, e.g. `library(tidyverse); df %>% gather(course, grade, GSF3A3U:WIN3B3DU) %>% ggplot(aes(x = course, y = grade)) + geom_point()`

Comment: @alistaire Thank you, the layout looks exactly right now, but for some reason the grades are not displaying correctly, it just shows non-stop dots to the end.

Comment: That could be a font or graphics device issue. Try specifying a font you know has the characters you need.

Comment: Oh, what I meant was is that the dots in the scatterplot are just all lined up to the top for the grades, if I use a line, the line is just straight to the top as well for each course, it's not taking the grades into account, it seems.

Comment: Nevermind, it works, was a mistake on my end, thanks a lot @alistaire. It was because I had added too many entries and it cluttered up, after reducing it to 5 students, it worked.

Comment: You could also use `geom_jitter` or translucent points to show more data. Or boxplots, I guess.